# problem in code when update jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code.
Works well with jquery 1.5.2, now i updated to 1.6 and the the delete button doesn't work

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/NnaEW/) works well, but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zE7Qw/), the button delete doesn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
            var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
            var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

            var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

            newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
            $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

            if (newNum == 5)
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });

        $('#btnDel').click(function() {
            var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

            $('#input' + num).remove();
            $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

            if (num-1 == 1)
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });

        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });
</script>
```

Any idea?

Comment: You mean `$('.clonedInput:last').remove()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in jquery 1.6 attr() function has changed and in some cases you should use prop(). In [1.6.1](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/) they re-introduced some changes for compatibilty. look [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for prop() specification

Taken from jquery site:

> The difference between attributes and
>   properties can be important in
>   specific situations. Before jQuery
>   1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when
>   retrieving some attributes, which
>   could cause inconsistent behavior. As
>   of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method
>   provides a way to explicitly retrieve
>   property values, while .attr() only
>   retrieves attributes.

Comment: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/  It is the first point mentioned in that blog post.

Comment: This is plain wrong. You do **not** *have to* use `prop()`. You make it sound as if `attr()` would be deprecated.

Comment: @Tomalak you are right i changed slightly my answer so that it's not confusing! I didn't mean that prop is discontinued, i just meant that in 1.6 there are cases when attr() doesn't work as it did in 1.5.2

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that you have to use `attr()` correctly. `disabled` is a boolean attribute, to enable an element you must *remove* it, not set it to the empty string. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/zjcfN/

That `prop()` works is more of an accident than anything else. You can (and should!) continue to use `attr()` to work with HTML element attributes, and as of jQuery 1.6 you can additionally use `prop()` to work with DOM object properties.

The following works perfectly in jQuery 1.6:

```
// disable an element
$("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
// enable an element
$("input").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: i tested with $('#btnDel').removeAttr('disabled','disabled'); Doesn't work

Comment: @Fel Where did I say `removeAttr('disabled','disabled')`? Also, is the jsFiddle working for you?

Comment: but..."In the majority of cases, prop() does what attr() used to do. Replacing calls to attr() with prop() in your code will generally work."  - relevant question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr